# JQuery scrollLocal issues

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have been trying to get a jquery plugin working with no success. The plugin is "scrollLocal" part of "scrollTo" and I am trying to make the page scroll horizontally to a div placed just outside of the page.

From what I can see there are no major issues with the code, but for some reason it doesnt perform the animation.

I have it all marked up here:

http://pastebin.com/6QeWprH3

Can anyone find a fix for this issue OR provide an alternative that does the same job?

EDIT: For reference I am trying to an effect similar to: http://michel-doudin.com/

Thanks!!

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Try jscrollpane, very easy to use and you can customize everything http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/